# Sort by modified date in custom search core results webpart

Tags: 2010, development, search, managed-property, ordering

I have created a custom search results web part which implements some simple sorting, for example i have this piece of code which allows me to sort it desc/asc by title:

```
    CoreResultsDatasource dataSource = this.DataSource as CoreResultsDatasource;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrderByProperty))
    {
       // change the sortorder
       dataSource.SortOrder.Clear();
       dataSource.SortOrder.Add(OrderByProperty, SortDirection);
    }
```

Basically it works for the title, but when i want to sort by Modified Date, it doesnt work, i get an error in the webapart:

> Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema
>   settings.

I did try to add it in:
Core Search Results Display Metadata => Properties

But still nothing happens.

Any idea how can i do it?

PS: I tried to pass "ModifiedDate" and i tried to pass "LastModifiedTime"
Another strange issue i notice is that when i pass a title outside of search center it breaks i get an "Internal error" no errors in the log.

Comment: When you are trying to sort by Modified Date, which OrderByProperty name you are passing?

Comment: I tried: "ModifiedDate" and i tried "LastModifiedTime"

Comment: Ivan is correct, you should use exact managed property name, for Modified date it is `write` managed property. Also, delete all none existing managed properties from Core Search Results Display Metadata => Properties to error disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can only provide sorting on managed properties. Look for the exact name of the managed property in central administration. I have similar web part and it works for me. Maybe look if the crawled property is correctly assigned to managed property.

Comment: Same web part? Does it work also outside of search center? And the filter works perfectly? And what peoperty exactly you use?

Comment: yes it works outside of search centre. using it for showing last 5 documents by mod date. in text box for order property name i have "LastModifiedTime", in fixed query : scope:"MyDocuments". Probably look if 2 or more web parts on one page does not have the same value in 'Cross web part query id'. i had issues with this.

Comment: also be aware that if you are doing filtering in fixed query there are som strange restrictions and rules, look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff394509.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872310.aspx)

Comment: Yes Ivan i think i have same webpart as you do, but when i add this LastModifiedTime, i get "Property doesn't exist or is used in a manner inconsistent with schema settings. 
" Although it is default property ...

Comment: probably past here all the sections where you are using this property, maybe there is really just small typo